# Retrieving data from database and writing new data into mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have the following code running on Tomcat and the loop is not working. Everytime I am trying to check for new data in the table called "enero", the conditions are not followed correctly and only the first action is completed... ending in duplicates records entered in the table.

Can you help please!

```
<%-- <jsp:getProperty name="beanInstanceName" property="propertyName"/> --%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%  
String REF=request.getParameter("d_ref");
String DATE=request.getParameter("i_date");
String UBC=request.getParameter("i_ubc");
%>
<%

    try
    {
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        //Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db1","","");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/labacacias?user=root&password=letmein");
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String query;
        query="SELECT * FROM enero";
        boolean b=false;
        ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);      
        while (resultSet.next())
        {

        if (REF.equals(resultSet.getString(1)) && DATE.equals(resultSet.getString(2)) && UBC.equals(resultSet.getString(3)))

            {
            out.println("Datos ya han sido adjuntados anteriormente!");
            out.println("<a href=\"EneroU.jsp\">Click Aqui para Adjuntar nuevos Resultados</a>");
            break;                  
            }               
        if (!REF.equals(resultSet.getString(1)) && !DATE.equals(resultSet.getString(2)) && !UBC.equals(resultSet.getString(3)))
            {
            pageContext.forward("InsertE.jsp");
            break;          
            }   

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(e.toString());
    }

%>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you if condition. There are many && in it.

If first action is completed every time there might be a possibility that the strings in resultset and parameters are fulfilling the if condition.

Comment: should I just have one condition only?

Comment: I left only one condition, and I am entering a duplicate value, but it is still creating a new entry on the table....not sure what else to do!

Comment: I mean that Depending on your logic. you can use || in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the correct approach here. You seem to be selecting all rows from the table and comparing them one at a time to the details coming in as request parameters. If they all match, you say the data already exists, otherwise if the values passed in do not match you forward to a different page. Unless your table has only one row in it then you're going to get strange results.

What would make more sense would be to select from your table where col1= REF and col2 = DATE and col3 = UBC. If rs.next() == false, pageContext.forward(), else out.println("Datos ya han sido adjuntados anteriormente!")

Comment: Thanks DaveHowes.... how do I make sure that all data in the table is checked and not just one row? so you say that the while loop is incorrect? how do I incorporate the col1=REF and col2=DATE and col3= UBC in my code? sorry to askf for this much, but I am new on this and I am the point that I cannot see the answer in front of me...  I have been trying to resolve this issue in the last 2 days!

Comment: DaveHowes... this is what I changed it for, but now I get a syntax error... the new code is:                                              and the error is this:                      An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /CreateE.jsp
Incompatible operand types ResultSet and boolean
28:   while (resultSet.next())
29:   {
30:   
31:   if (resultSet==false)  
32:    {
33:    pageContext.forward("InsertE.jsp");
34:    }

Comment: It's a big topic with no short answer. You need a "WHERE" clause in your SQL statement and you should consider using a PreparedStatement to supply the values to the WHERE clause. There are plenty of examples on the web of how to do this, so Google is probably your friend here.

Comment: OK - resultSet.next() moves you to the next row in the resultset, returning false if you've reached the end. In our case, if resultSet.next() returns false, it means the row does not exists and you need to insert a new one. We no longer have a need for a loop, so you can remove line 28 and 31, replacing them with if ( resultSet.next()) { pageContext.forward("InsertE.jsp")} else { out.println("...."); }

Comment: Hi Dave, I have tried the PreparedStatement as suggested... please see below, but the check for duplicates is not working, it is going to InsertE.jsp straight away even tho I am using duplicate records on purpose....

Comment: connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db1","","");  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/labacacias?user=root&password=letmein");
  String query;
  query="SELECT referencia FROM enero";
  boolean b=false;
  PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
  ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);

Comment: while (!resultSet.last() || (!b))
  {if (resultSet.getString("referencia").compareTo("REF")==0)
   {
   b=true; 
   out.println("Datos ya han sido adjuntados anteriormente!");out.println("<a href=\"EneroU.jsp\">Click Aqui para Adjuntar nuevos Resultados</a>");
   break;
   }    
  if (!b){
   pageContext.forward("InsertE.jsp");
   break;
   }

Comment: You need the WHERE clause in your select statement which will tell you if the specific row you are looking for exists. There's no need for the while loop if you do that. If the specific row you are interested in exists you put the message out, if it doesn't ( ie rs.next() == false ), then you forward to the insertE.jsp page